# Java: Fill a dynamic list from a generic class

Tags: java, android, list, generics

I have a class:

```
public class Car {
    public int year;
    public String model;
}
```

and a list:

```
List<Car> list = new DB<>(new Car()).getList();
```

I need to fill that list from my class Car to fill for example an json array or a table from a sqlite db.

Below I have my generic class that it suppose to fill it:

```
public class DB<T>{
   private T type;
   public DB(T type){this.type = type;}

   public List<T> getList(){
      List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
         T object = (T)type.getClass().newInstance();// this line doesn't work
         list.add(object);
      }
      return list;
   }
}
```

My problem lies when I try to make a new instance of 'T' to add a new and different object in my list.

I tried doing something like this:

```
T object = new T();
```

But returns a empty object, so I tried doing a cast (the one that I did in my generic class) and my console gave me this error:

> java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class
>   com.example.myprojects.Car; no empty constructor

I don't know if I'm missing something, so my question is why this doesn't let me create a new instance or if there's another workaround that would help me create a new instance?

**Edit:** Following Nicola's Answer I rewritten my generic class like this:

```
public class DB<T>{
  private Class<T> type;
  public DB(Class<T> type){this.type = type;}

  public List<T> getList() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
     List<T> a = new ArrayList<>();
     try{
        a.add(type.newInstance());// Still can't instance
     }cath(Exeption e){e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
  return a;
}
```

But my console continues to show the same mistake , even declared an empty constructor in my class `Car`.

Comment: What do you mean by "this line doesn't work"? What error does the compiler throw?

Comment: What about `List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();`? If you've a car collection `cars` for this list, then you can use `List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>(cars);`. It's easier than `DB<T>` and you can still have read, update, insert and delete operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it is self-explanatory

> can't instantiate class com.example.myprojects.Car; no empty
>   constructor

Indeed calling [Class#newInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) will create dynamically a new instance of the class using the **empty constructor** (constructor with no parameters) so if you don't define a empty constructor in your class `Car`, you will get this exception.

If the empty constructor is not good enough for you, you can still get a given constructor by reflection using [`Class#getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-), then from the `Constructor` instance you can call [`Constructor#newInstance(Object... initargs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) to create your instance.

---

Your class `DB` doesn't need to have **an explicit instance of the target class**, only the **target class instance** is needed. In other words, it should be rewritten as next:

```
 public class DB<T>{
    private Class<T> type;
    public DB(Class<T> type){this.type = type;}

    public List<T> getList() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return Arrays.asList(type.newInstance(), type.newInstance());
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to get a `List` of `Car` as next

```
List<Car> list = new DB<>(Car.class).getList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In class `Car` add empty constructor:

```
 public Car() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare your inner classes as static?

```
public static class Car {
    public int year;
    public String model;
}
```